# Why was this closed as not being focused?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

[How can I find where a user has clicked on a Polyline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62988611/how-can-i-find-where-a-user-has-clicked-on-a-polyline)
The question is a single question. I don't understand how this can be more focused.

Update: Thanks for the upvotes, it's now been reopened. But it's been downvoted twice and has a close vote with no explanation or comment as to why. I'd like to see people give a reason for downvoting (maybe just click from a list) and actually have to comment to vote for a close, otherwise you have no way of knowing what they think the problem is.

Comment: I guess the people who voted are in the best situation to answer that. Beats me.

Comment: *"has a close vote with no explanation or comment as to why ... actually have to comment to vote for a close"* - The comment is right there linking to the proposed duplicate, which you claim doesn't answer your question.... yet the answer to that question is the same as the answer to yours, *use the 3rd parameter of the onClick event*

Comment: "otherwise you have no way of knowing what they think the problem is." - indeed. You also don't know why people are upvoting. It's a complete blank.

Comment: @Nick that answer is for the onClick event of the map, which would give me the lat/long but won't tell me if the user clicked on the line or not. I wanted to get a click event from the line itself.

Answer (score -8):

It might have been to do with the language used to describe the problem.

"If I add a Polyline to my map with a click function"

Makes it sound like your asking about how to add a polyline by clicking on the map, where as what you intended was how to manage the event fired when you click a polyline already displayed.

I imagine whoever flagged it didn't quite grasp that.

Comment: But you need (I think) three votes to close a question so more than one person either didn't read the question properly or had other issues.